# Will the jQuery .load() ajax function work with local files inside of phonegap?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, same-origin-policy

I am working on a mobile web-app project that will eventually be packaged with phonegap.
I am using:

```
$('#mainContainer').load('sectionOne.html', function() { /* do something once page has loaded */ });
```

to load in the various sections of my application as the user navigates to them.

Given that I am accessing pages that are local to the main index.html page, I should not encounter cross-domain issues; however, when testing in Google Chrome, I found the browser couldn't use the `.load()` jquery function when running the index file locally (`file:///C:/...`). The `.load()` function work perfectly fine when the page is accessed from a server (including from `http://localhost/...`).

Since my page navigation system hinges on the `.load()` function, can anyone verify that it will work as I want to to within the phonegap shell when running locally (i.e. inside of a webview) on devices like iPhone, iPads and android phones/tablets? If this won't work, does anyone have a suggestion for how to rework this system while still keeping my sections as separate html files?

Comment: yes ofcourse it should work and will work

Comment: Thank you for responding